# Side Menu Route

Tags: ionic-framework, routes, ionic5, side-menu

I'm trying to implement a side menu in my app ionic 5. but i can't seem to do so. when i run the app, it will go to home page but won't go to other pages like stats page, savings page. triedto look at the console log for errors but there were no errors.

This is my html page
[html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpiXJ.png)

This is routing-module.ts

[routing module page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAQ4y.png)

This is my console log page.
[Console page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzLMG.png)

It doesn't state any error but it won't go to the page i want either

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML code instead of `routerLink="home"` change it to `[routerLink]="['/home']"`. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check your menu-rooting.module.ts to check if the pages are defined as children of the menu page.For example: `children: [{path: 'statistics',loadChildren: () => import('../statistics/statistics.module').then(m => m.StatisticsPageModule)}]`